# After connecting NLB, rtmps broadcasting connection is established and then not

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-nlb

EC2 is using the free tier. After creating an external domain, while registering it in route53, I use A record - Direct connection to the instance IP (existing domain) / A record - Connecting to NLB (live. Existing domain), and on the external domain site, the name server of that site and the name of route53 are used. The server is also registered. And the certificate is an SSL certificate registered on the instance itself with certbot, and the certificate for NLB is issued by ACM with live added in front of the domain. In this state, if you send a request to (rtmp://existing domain) to (rtmps://live.existing domain) and start broadcasting with OBS, It's connected and then it's not connected, and the status goes back and forth. What you can check through monitoring is as follows. Please advise.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD0Lc.png)

It's not that it doesn't work at all, and even when I monitor it, I don't know what the problem is, so there aren't many methods I've tried yet.